# Vertica: repeat category from previous period if it not listed in current

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to make some sort of running total in table with gaps. I have a period, a category and a value, and I want to list all categories used in current and previous periods for given `storage_id` even if there is no value of that category in current period.

My data:

```
period|storage_id|category|value|
------|----------|--------|-----|
     1|         1|a       |foo  |
     2|         1|b       |bar  |
     3|         1|a       |bar  |
     3|         1|b       |foo  |
     1|         2|a       |foo  |
     2|         2|b       |bar  |
     4|         2|c       |foo  |
```

My goal:

```
period|storage_id|category|value|
------|----------|--------|-----|
     1|         1|a       |foo  |
     2|         1|a       |NULL |
     2|         1|b       |bar  |
     3|         1|a       |bar  |
     3|         1|b       |foo  |
     1|         2|a       |foo  |
     2|         2|a       |NULL |
     2|         2|b       |bar  |
     4|         2|a       |NULL |
     4|         2|b       |NULL |
     4|         2|c       |foo  |
```

I managed to make it using temporary table and 2 self-joins. Is there more efficient way to do that, e.g., using window functions?

Reproducible example:

```
 CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt (
        storage_id int
    ,   category varchar(255)
    ,   value varchar(255)
    ,   period int
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO tt
SELECT 1, 'a', 'foo', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'b', 'bar', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'a', 'bar', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'b', 'foo', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a', 'foo', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b', 'bar', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'c', 'foo', 4
;
```

My imperfect solution:

```
WITH
cat as (
SELECT  
    t1.category
,   t1.storage_id
,   t2.period
FROM
    tt as t1 join tt as t2
    on t1.storage_id = t2.storage_id
    and t1.period <= t2.period
GROUP BY 
    t1.category
,   t1.storage_id
,   t2.period
)
SELECT
    cat.period
,   cat.storage_id
,   cat.category
,   tt.value    
FROM cat
    LEFT JOIN tt
    ON tt.category = cat.category
    and tt.storage_id = cat.storage_id  
    and tt.period = cat.period
ORDER BY
    storage_id, period;

11 rows, 178 ms
```

Comment: Please do not tag databases not affected. Postgres and Vertica are two very different products (even though created by the same lead architect)

Comment: I don't understand why 4/1/a is not in your result set.

Comment: I don't have any of categories in storage 1, period 4 so 4/1/a is not listed. Also, I don't have any of categories in storage 2, period 3 so 3/2/a is not listed too.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to list all categories used in current and previous periods even if there is no value of that category in current period.

I don't see how your result set illustrates this, because you have not carried all results to the end.

For the problem you *describe*, the following should do what you want:

```
select p.period, sc.storage_id, sc.category, tt.value
from (select distinct period from tt) p join
     (select storage_id, category, min(period) as first_period
      from tt
      group by 1, 2
     ) sc
     on p.period >= sc.first_period left join
     tt
     on tt.period = p.period and
        tt.storage_id = sc.storage_id and
        tt.category = sc.category
order by p.period, sc.storage_id, sc.category;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f98286a77db4b163179c682420fc24d) is a db<>fiddle.

I can't figure out the actual logic that produces the result set you want.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I want to list all categories for given storage_id. Updated the question.

Comment: @AndreyGoloborodko . . . You may want to ask a new question if you want to get it answered.